# Sort NSDictionary keys as NSDate

Tags: ios, sorting, nsdate, nsdictionary

I'm developing an iOS 4 application with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I have a `NSMutableDictionary` where **keys** are `NSDate` and **values** are `NSMutableString`.

When I have filled up the **NSMutableDictionary** I want to sort its keys but I don't know how can I do it.

I want first January dates, then February and so on.

The `NSDate` key format is **dd/mm/yyyy**.

How can I sort those keys when `NSMutableDictionary` has all its keys and values? (I'm not going to add more).

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary, as lookup is based on the key, not an index. You would need to convert it to an array first.

Comment: See here from SO's very own Ole Begemann. The example is for driving a table view but the principles should apply to your case. 
http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/tutorial-how-to-sort-and-group-uitableview-by-date/

Comment: And this could be an implementation of sorted NSMutableDictionary: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a pretty standard thing, however, you may not **sort** an NSDictionary - you may sort an array you get from the dictionary however.

This is what I'd do:

```
// get all keys into array
NSArray * keys = [your_dictionary allKeys];

// sort it
NSArray * sorted_keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

// now, access the values in order
for (NSDate * key in sorted_keys)
{
  // get value
  NSMutableString * your_value = [your_dictionary valueForKey: key];

  // perform operations
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this code:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [[myDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

But note that you cannot sort a dictionary, as it is based on key-value lookups, not indexed lookups.

Comment: Ok. With this code I will have in another array all keys sorted, and then I could use it to access dictionary values by an order, isn't it?