# How to sort an array of dictionary by date?

Tags: ios, swift2, nsarray, nsdate, nsdictionary

I am getting some post from Facebook for my application, I have all post data into a dictionary and that dictionary is in array. Now I have the post time from the Facebook which is in dictionary as string. I want to sort that array according to latest post which is known by the post time. I had seen several answers on SO but they did in a single dictionary I want to do that from different dictionary. [image]

This is my array of dictionary from which I have to sort array according to dictionary postTime value.

Code:

```
var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
                    var tempArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                    for var i = 0; i < dicts.count; i++ {
                        var dic: NSMutableDictionary = dicts[i] as! NSMutableDictionary
                        let dateConverted: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dic["postTime"] as! String)!
                        dic["postTime"] = dateConverted
                        tempArray.addObject(dic)
                    }
                    var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "postTime", ascending: true)
                    var descriptors: NSArray = [descriptor]
                    var sortedArray: NSArray = tempArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors(descriptors as! [NSSortDescriptor])
                    NSLog("%@", sortedArray)
```

dicts is my array of dictionary and i have to take the post time which is seen in the image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529620/sort-nsdictionary-keys-as-nsdate

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083408/sort-nsarray-of-custom-objects-by-their-nsdate-properties

Comment: do you want to sort dictionary? dictionary is unsorted collection. in reality you would like to sort an array.

Comment: I have to sort array but from the dictionary values

Comment: have u tried given answer ?????

Comment: first i have to convert it into swift then i try.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"'Time: 'yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss";


    NSMutableArray *tempArray=[NSMutableArray new];
    for(NSInteger i=0;i<yourArrayOfDic.count ;i++){
        NSMutableDictionary *dic =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[yourArrayOfDic objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSDate *dateConverted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dic valueForKey:@"time"]];
        [dic setValue:dateConverted forKey:@"time"];
        [tempArray addObject:dic];
    }


    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"time" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray=[tempArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
    NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

// In Swift.. i m weak in swift but objective c to swift may help u . let me know it work or not !!!!!

```
var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "'Time: 'yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss"
var tempArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
for var i = 0; i < yourArrayOfDic.count; i++ {
    var dic: NSMutableDictionary = yourArrayOfDic[i]
    var dateConverted: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dic["time"])
    dic["time"] = dateConverted
    tempArray.addObject(dic)
}
var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "time", ascending: true)
var descriptors: NSArray = [descriptor]
var sortedArray: NSArray = tempArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors(descriptors)
NSLog("%@", sortedArray)
```

Comment: On this line let dateConverted: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dic["postTime"])   it shows an error of Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to expected argument type 'String'.

Comment: var dateConverted: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dic["time"] as! String)

Comment: Now its getting crashed showing unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104698/discussion-between-shahin-ali-agharia-and-yagnesh-dobariya).

Answer (score 0):

IOS Swift 3.2

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
//   dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
let tempArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
for i in 0 ..< self.yourarr.count{
    var dicdata  = self.yourarr[i] as! [String : Any]

    var dateConverted = dateFormatter.date(from: dicdata["time"] as! String)
    dicdata["time"] = dateConverted
                    tempArray.add(dicdata)
 }
 var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "time", ascending: true)
 var descriptors: NSArray = [descriptor]
 var sortedArray: NSArray = tempArray.sortedArray(using: descriptors as! [NSSortDescriptor]) as NSArray
 NSLog("%@", sortedArray)
```